# Count NULL or whitespace fields in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to count how many `NULLs` and whitespaces contains a `Table` in `SQLite`?

The query below works for `NULL or empty` case, but how to handle whitespaces? Any ideas?

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM Table 
 WHERE Column IS NULL 
       OR Column = ''; // fine for 'NULL or empty'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `trim()`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Table
WHERE Column IS NULL OR trim(Column, ' ') = '';
```

This uses the explicit 2-argument form of `trim()`.  The second argument is a list of characters you might want to remove from the ends of the string.  You can add other characters to it.